# Why Comparator.comparingInt not working in Arrays.sort() in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

I am trying to sort a list of Interval class:

```
class Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; }
    Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; }
}
```

I tried to use the code below:

```
Arrays.sort(intervals, Comparator.comparingInt(interval -> interval.start));
```

but it has compiling errors:

```
java: no suitable method found for sort(java.util.List<Interval>,java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object>)
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; java.util.List<Interval> cannot be converted to T[]))
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],int,int,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

However, when I use:

```
intervals.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(interval -> interval.start));
```

it's working properly.

Any reasons behind this?

Comment: Are you trying to sort a List with Arrays.sort? Use Collections.sort

Comment: Exactly what Eran says. Both sorting an Array with Arrays.sort and sorting a List with Collections.sort work just as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any reasons behind this?

A `List` isn't an array (even if it's an `ArrayList`: that merely describes how the data is stored internally), and so is not applicable to methods accepting array parameters.